# Is it possible to write into excel file line by line using java and Apache POI libraries

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, apache-poi

I am trying to write into my excel file line by line. Code will run fine with no error. but when i try to open the excel file, one popup appears and says that :
"We found a problem with some content in the excel file. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?"

Normally I use FileOutputStream outside the loop in which I work with the data and use .setCellValue(Value). But when I use it inside the loop, the excel file wont get updated. In the code below, after writing the excel I am closing and reopening the excel file. I tried available solutions but didn't work.
Any help is appreciated.

below is the code :

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
Package Excel;

import java.io.FileInputStream;    
import java.io.FileOutputStream;    
import java.io.IOException;    
import java.io.InputStream;    
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;    
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;    
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;    
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;    
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class testTool {

static WebDriver driver;
public static FileInputStream ACF;
public static FileOutputStream fos;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/PACon_InputPath.properties");
    properties.load(inputStream);

    int i = 1;

    ACF = new FileInputStream(properties.getProperty("inputFilePath"));
    XSSFWorkbook workBk = new XSSFWorkbook(ACF);
    XSSFSheet Workable_Dump_Data = workBk.getSheet("Workable Dump Data");

    for (i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {

        System.out.println("\n````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````Row - " + i);

        XSSFRow Rw = Workable_Dump_Data.getRow(i);

        XSSFCell Account_Name = Rw.getCell(3); // Fetching Account name from the excel
        String accountName = Account_Name.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("Account Name : " + accountName);

        XSSFCell Physical_address = Rw.getCell(3); // Fetching Physical Address from the excel
        String physicalAddress = Physical_address.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("Physical Address : " + physicalAddress);

        boolean flag1 = false;
        if (accountName.equals("") || physicalAddress.equals(""))
        {

            XSSFCell str13 = Rw.getCell(15);
            str13.setCellValue("Empty Fields");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(properties.getProperty("inputFilePath"), true);
                workBk.write(fos); // writing to Excel and continue
                fos.close();
                workBk = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(properties.getProperty("inputFilePath")));
                continue;
        }
        else
        {
            XSSFCell str13 = Rw.getCell(15);
            str13.setCellValue("Fields Are Available");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(properties.getProperty("inputFilePath"), true);
                workBk.write(fos); // writing to Excel and continue
                fos.close();
                workBk = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(properties.getProperty("inputFilePath")));
                continue;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Successfully writen in the excel sheet");

}

}
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Which version of POI are you using?

Comment: I am using POI 3.15

Comment: Why are you trying to write the file after every line change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a work around for my requirement. We can put the FileOutputStream inside the loop, one thing we need to keep in mind is to save and open excel file after writing into it for every iteration.

steps will be like:
 1. Open excel file (FileInputStream)
 2. Set value to cells (.setCellValue())
 3. Write into excel (workBk.write(fos))
 4. Save the excel file (fos.close())
 5. Open excel again (See code below)
 6. Increment loop
          AND repeat....

The change i made in my previous code :

1st (Removed True from the end)

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(properties.getProperty("inputFilePath"));
```

2nd (Added before continue;)

```
Workable_Dump_Data = workBk.getSheet("Workable Dump Data");
```

Refer full code below :

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class testTool {

public static FileOutputStream fos;
public static FileInputStream ACF;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/PACon_InputPath.properties");
    properties.load(inputStream);

    try {
        ACF = new FileInputStream(properties.getProperty("inputFilePath"));
        XSSFWorkbook workBk = new XSSFWorkbook(ACF);
        XSSFSheet Workable_Dump_Data = workBk.getSheet("Workable Dump Data");

        int i = 1;

        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

            System.out.println("\n````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````Row - " + i);

            XSSFRow Rw = Workable_Dump_Data.getRow(i);

            /*if (i == 6) // test if it update excel, if tool stops in between
            {
                String accountTest = "";
                XSSFCell Account_Name = Rw.getCell(22);
                accountTest = Account_Name.getStringCellValue();
            }*/

            XSSFCell Account_Name = Rw.getCell(3); // Fetching Account name from the excel
            String accountName = Account_Name.getStringCellValue();
            System.out.println("Account Name : " + accountName);

            XSSFCell Physical_address = Rw.getCell(3); // Fetching Physical Address from the excel
            String physicalAddress = Physical_address.getStringCellValue();
            System.out.println("Physical Address : " + physicalAddress);

            boolean flag1 = false;
            if (accountName.equals("") || physicalAddress.equals(""))
            {

                XSSFCell str13 = Rw.getCell(15);
                str13.setCellValue("Empty Fields");
                fos = new FileOutputStream(properties.getProperty("inputFilePath"));
                    workBk.write(fos); // writing to Excel and continue
                    fos.close();
                    workBk = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(properties.getProperty("inputFilePath")));
                    Workable_Dump_Data = workBk.getSheet("Workable Dump Data");
                    continue;
            }
            else
            {
                XSSFCell str13 = Rw.getCell(15);
                str13.setCellValue("Fields Are Available" + i);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(properties.getProperty("inputFilePath"));
                    workBk.write(fos); // writing to Excel and continue
                    fos.close();
                    workBk = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(properties.getProperty("inputFilePath")));
                    Workable_Dump_Data = workBk.getSheet("Workable Dump Data");
                    continue;
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Do something better with the Exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        fos.close();
        System.out.println("Successfully writen in the excel sheet");
    }
}

}
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Thanks for the help @Gagravarr and @sirandy :)

Answer (score 1):

Just take away the true in the FileOutputStream constructor.

Also here is your code a little refactored:

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class testTool {

    public static FileInputStream ACF;
    public static FileOutputStream fos;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/PACon_InputPath.properties");
        properties.load(inputStream);

        try {
            ACF = new FileInputStream(properties.getProperty("inputFilePath"));
            XSSFWorkbook workBk = new XSSFWorkbook(ACF);
            XSSFSheet Workable_Dump_Data = workBk.getSheet("Workable Dump Data");

            int i = 1;

            for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

                System.out.println("\n````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````Row - " + i);

                XSSFRow Rw = Workable_Dump_Data.getRow(i);

                XSSFCell Account_Name = Rw.getCell(3); // Fetching Account name from the excel
                String accountName = Account_Name.getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println("Account Name : " + accountName);

                XSSFCell Physical_address = Rw.getCell(3); // Fetching Physical Address from the excel
                String physicalAddress = Physical_address.getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println("Physical Address : " + physicalAddress);

                XSSFCell str13 = Rw.getCell(15);
                boolean flag1 = false;
                if (accountName.equals("") || physicalAddress.equals("")) {
                    str13.setCellValue("Empty Fields");
                } else {
                    str13.setCellValue("Fields Are Available");
                }
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(properties.getProperty("inputFilePath")); 
            workBk.write(fos); // writing to Excel and continue
            fos.close();
            ACF.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Do something better with the Exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            System.out.println("Successfully writen in the excel sheet");
        }
    }

}
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Thanks @sirandy for the reply, but still it doesn't solve my problem. FileOutputStream in your code is again outside the **for loop**, which means it will write into the excel in the end after the loop is done, and not with each iteration.

Comment: @Deep You generally shouldn't write out the file until you're done changing it, so this code looks like the right approach!

Comment: That's Right. Actually I am working on a large excel file with around 1000 records in it. The problem arise when I run tool and at an event of error (say at row 991) all the data that was captured is lost. So I'll have to run the tool again for same set of records. That's way i need a way to write & save the excel file with each iteration. Hope this make sense..!!